# Streaming App, Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema for subject

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have a source connector that pushes to a newly created topic. "key.converter" and "value.converter" aren't configured so the conversion is done using Avro.

> ```
> "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
> "value.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
> ```

When Kafka Connect populates this topic, it creates a schema in the registry with the subjects names "topic-name-key" and "topic-name-value". This schema for example may have a field configured like this

```
"fields: [{"name" : "user_id", "type" : "long"}]
```

But when records are being pulled into a streaming app, Kafka's code (Kafka-Streams:3.0.1) has a schema accompanying the data. And sometimes (not always) the associated schema has a different datatype (user_id is int rather than long).

```
"fields: [{"name" : "user_id", "type" : "int"}]
```

And the an exceptions is thrown with this message "Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema for subject".

Questions:

1. Why does the schema accompany an Avro message when schemas.enable = false?
2. Why doesn't Kafka use the associated schema rather than look it up from the schema registry, compare the registry version, and complain about incompatibility?

Error:

> org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in
> process. taskId=0_1, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000,
> topic=member_device_5, partition=1, offset=0,
> stacktrace=org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException:
> Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema for
> subject
> "foo-campaign-KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000006-store-changelog-key";
> error code: 409

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the schema accompany an Avro message when schemas.enable = false?

Because Avro **always has a schema**. It cannot be disabled. That property is **only** applicable to `JSONConverter` (look at the source code).

> Why doesn't Kafka use the associated schema rather than look it up from the schema registry,

Kafka doesn't care. The Serde within your own app does. If you've used a specific schema, you'll need to modify your StreamsConfig property map to enable "specific.avro.reader". Otherwise, it'll use the schema that's in the registry during deserialization.

Secondly, `foo-campaign-KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000006-store-changelog-key` is its own schema in the Registry, and has no direct relation to the topic that your Connector has written to Kafka.

Most importantly, Avro long types cannot be downcast to int types

Comment: "foo-campaign-KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000006-store-changelog-key" is a schema (subject) automatically registered for a KStream to KStream join in the streaming app. This schema sometimes conflicts with the schema embedded in the message (where a data-type may varies from into to long). KafkaStreams is parsing the avro message's schema, then comparing it to a registered schema; which was not registered by me. This only happens with a JOIN.

Comment: Even if it "sometimes conflicts", then you will end up with `incompatible with an earlier schema`. Besides, your state-store creation should set the key-serde appropriately using `Materialized.with`, and if that's being changed, you should reset the streams app and delete the associated schemas. Ideally, table keys aren't Avro anyway for this very reason